# Parse server payments not working

Tags: stripe-payments, parse-server

I have an app that used to be on Parse.com and now is migrated to the open source parse server running on elastic beanstalk. The app uses Stripe for payments and everything worked fine before, but after migrating to parse server, the payments are now failing. Does anyone know of something they changed or anyone had a similar problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that the module delivered with Parse hosted no longer works on Parse-server. I am sure that Stripe has a node module which you could install and use instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Cloud Code, create a route in your index.js file to take care of charges. Make a post route and you can call it via jquery post or from a form. I use body-parser in index.js to retreive the post data.